# Forward request to another rest service using filter

Tags: java, rest, servlets, jersey-2.0

I am writing a servlet filter to forward Jersy requests based on certain condition. But they does not seem to forwarding.

```
public class SampleFilter
    extends GenericFilterBean
{    
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        String generateRedirectUrl=FormURL((HttpServletRequest)req);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher(generateRedirectUrl);        
        dispatcher.forward(req, resp);        

    }

    private String FormURL(HttpServletRequest req)
    {
        // get the request check if it contains the customer
        String reqUrl = req.getRequestURI();
        log.info("Original Url is"+reqUrl);
        if(reqUrl.contains("test"))
        {
            return "/api/abcd/" +"test";
        }
         return "Someurl";

    }

}
```

I need to forward the url as below.

```
Original: http://localhost/api/test/1234/true

New URL:http://localhost/api/abcd/1234/true
```

Am I doing any thing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Am I doing any thing wrong."

In general I think this will work - you can forward from a filter, but your logic is wrong.

Using your rule below:

```
Original: http://localhost/api/test/1234/true
New URL:http://localhost/api/abcd/1234/true
```

The code:

```
if(reqUrl.contains("test"))
    {
        return "/api/abcd/" +"test";
    }
```

will produce `/api/abcd/test` which is not what you're after.

I would do something like the following:

```
 private String formURL(HttpServletRequest req) {
    // get the request check if it contains the customer
    String reqUrl = req.getRequestURI();
    if (log.isInfoEnabled() {
      log.info("Original Url is"+reqUrl);
    }
    if(reqUrl.contains("test")) {
      return reqUrl.replace("test", "abcd");
    }
    return "Someurl";
```

Also, the code is very brutal. This will also change the URL

> http://test.site.com/abd/def
>   to
>   http://abcd.site.com/abd/def

which is probably not what you want. You'll probably need to either do more clever string manipulation or convert to something like the `URI` class which will allow you to target the path more accurately.

Hope this helps,

Will